Trying to use radio IC
I took a clock radio apart: Scott CX81: https://picclick.fr/Scott-CX-81-Radio-r%C3%A9veil-double-alarme-Ecran-333884371576.html hoping I cound find a quartz crystal oscillator (for the clock) inside, so I could build a crude AM transmitter with it, sadly I only found one of this all in one LM8562 clock chips inside
However I was pleasantly suprised to see that radio part used a separate circuit board on a cable, based around an CD2003GP IC: https://www.ak-modul-bus.de/cat/documentation/CD2003.pdf
Now, in the datasheet it says I can drive this chip with 1.8-7V so I was thinking of isolating this board, drive it with 1 AA battery and hook small speaker or headphones to it, to make portable radio but I cannot seam to figure out, what pin on this cable is Power
Here are pictures of the circuit board
https://imgbox.com/3QK7XC5x
https://imgbox.com/FQBkSHSY
https://imgbox.com/0YVUaAbD
https://imgbox.com/wbut9lml
https://imgbox.com/2JKoFG62
https://imgbox.com/5FMNaczq
https://imgbox.com/bkEfWTsY
I was able to find ground is PIN is PIN3 (if circuit board is on its green side and rotated like on the pictures)
But the rest of the pins I was not able to find (I wasnt even able to mesure any voltage on any of this pins, when clock radio is on, but I did find out that if I connect my multimeter probe to PIN1 (looking from the radio cuircit side), when radio circuit is not plugged into the main board, the speaker would buzz
I also cant figure out, why are there only 3 pins
I would expect 4pins
A pin for power
A pin for power ground
A pin for audio out
A pin for oudio ground
Would also like to hook a proper 75ohm coaxial cable to it, and maybe add a stereo and RDS decoder to this
Sadly I didnt find any service manual or schematic for this clock radio, but I do wonder which test circuit (from radio ic schematic), they used
Hopefully someone smarter then me can figure this out

Please inline your images.

Line powered clocks often used the line frequency for the clock reference, not a crystal.

This CD2003GP chip is powered with a positive voltage on pin #6 of about +6V, with GROUND on pin #2. Four AA batteries in series would likely be enough.
Audio output ground on pin #9 is likely also tied to power ground on pin #2. Its audio output on pin #11 is too feeble to drive a loudspeaker...you'd want to add an audio amplifier having gain of 20 or 30.
I'd make a wild guess that the grey flat cable might contain:

Ground
DC voltage (+7)?
audio output


what confused me is that the chip can operate from 1.8 to 7V (why do much freedom in voltage)?
If I use bigger voltage, what advantage would this give me?
the radio uses CD2822A as amplifier chip, so will probably use that as well
Why did u guess 7V (is this some common voltage or something)?

+7V - a wild guess. Data sheet suggested +3V for their measurements. Don't you think a wide voltage range is a good thing? Since much logic  for the clock might use supply of +3.3 to +5V, this could work too. CD2822A has an even-wider acceptable supply range.

thnx, feed 3V to it, worked like a charm (Used an amplified BOSE speaker for a test) )(also remembered I could use continuity on my multimeter, so I just figured out which pin connected to the speaker) (PIN1: Speaker, 2 Power, 3 GND)
BTW: any good reverse engeneering tools, so I could make schematic out of this radio board (if not, any good steps to follow, when redrawing schematic from circuit board?)
